# How to compute the time taken in data re balancing in hazelcast, in case of a node failure?

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to figure out, how much time does hazelcast take to re-balance (re-partition) the data in case of a node failure. with varying backup counts.

Is there any way to figure this out. 
I tried using the migration listener, but its not notified in case of a node exit. The call back happens only in case of a node being added. I have tried this with three nodes, so as to rule out data being reclaimed from the backup, and thus no migration.

The other approach I tried was using the "isClusterSafe" API. So when a member is notified of node exit (using MembershipListener), I measure the time till the "isClusterSafe" API returns true.

Is there any other way to figure out this? And will my second approach give accurate values?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [MigrationListener](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MigrationListener.html) (not to be confused with [PartitionListener](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/partition/impl/PartitionListener.html)). Seems this has a hook to know when a partition's migration has started and finished. You can calculate the time taken per partition ID.

I would then use this in conjunction with the [MembershipListener](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MembershipListener.html) so that you could figure out when a partition has been migrated to another node due to a node failure (and not just some sort of scheduled rebalancing).

Comment: Mike, The MigrationListener is not being notified in the said case. I have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: Hey Rig, you mention you're using PartitionListener - this is a different event mechanism from MigrationListener. Check out the JavaDoc I link to in my answer.

Comment: My mistake :(. I used migration listener not partition listener.

Comment: Ah, I understand more now. It may be that your backup partitions are not being promoted to primary. This looks like an issue the HC developers thinking of addressing in 3.5:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/4272